# Rails app error - ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError Migrations are pending; run 'rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to resolve this issue

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, migration

The database is created, tables are created, data are there.

But after I restarted the Rails application, I got this error. The app is using MySQL.
What's the issue here?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Well are there pending migrations? What makes you think there are not any?

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

Simply run

```
rake db:migrate
```

There are migrations that need to be ran before your server can start. Learn what migrations are and how they are used in Rails [with this RailsGuide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html).

Run that `rake db:migrate` command any time you make a migration, or any time you create a new project. If you get an error saying that migrations are pending, this is the answer. Then try to start the server again.

Only if that doesn't work, try what is below.

#### If that doesn't work

Run these commands in this order:

1. `rake db:drop`
2. `rake db:create`
3. `rake db:migrate`
4. `rake db:seed`  -  This one is only necessary if you have seeded data.

### Remember, when in doubt: restart the server!

Answer (score 0):

just run `rake db:migrate` then start server, see then what happens, looks like existing migrations are yet not part of schema. Or you schema_migrations table might be missing some version value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`for me running just `bundle exec rake db:migrate` didn't resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

As one of the comments above, utilizing the following works for me:

```
rake db:drop

rake db:create

rake db:migrate
```

when `rake db:migrate` or restarting didn't help.