# ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError: Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, migration

NEWBIE: I am trying to set up the membership part of my site. I ran the following commands:

```
git checkout development 
git merge user_authentication 
git checkout -b stripe_integration 
bundle exec rails g migration CreatePlans
```

and received the this error:

```
ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError: Migrations are pending. To
resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

I've tried running it and other commands with no success. Below are links to other Stack Overflow answers to this issue that did not work for me and a full trace.

[Link from Stack Overflow 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658151/migrations-are-pending)

[Link from Stack Overflow 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339902/rails-app-error-activerecordpendingmigrationerror-migrations-are-pending-ru)

Full trace:

```
kmcrayton7:~/workspace (stripe_integration) $ bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
== 20151209220651 AddDeviseToUsers: migrating =================================
-- change_table(:users)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:331:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:331:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:375:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:454:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:490:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Table>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:489:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:489:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Table>'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/db/migrate/20151209220651_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `block in up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:349:in `change_table'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:649:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:641:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:406:in `method_missing'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/db/migrate/20151209220651_add_devise_to_users.rb:3:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:558:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:598:in `exec_migration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:577:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:752:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:992:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `block in transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:219:in `within_new_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:953:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:331:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:331:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:375:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:454:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:490:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Table>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:489:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:489:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Table>'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/db/migrate/20151209220651_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `block in up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:349:in `change_table'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:649:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:641:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:406:in `method_missing'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/db/migrate/20151209220651_add_devise_to_users.rb:3:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:558:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:598:in `exec_migration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:577:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:752:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:992:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `block in transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:219:in `within_new_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:953:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: email
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:331:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:331:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:375:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:454:in `add_column'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:490:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Table>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:489:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:489:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Table>'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/db/migrate/20151209220651_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `block in up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:349:in `change_table'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:649:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:621:in `say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:641:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:406:in `method_missing'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/db/migrate/20151209220651_add_devise_to_users.rb:3:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:558:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:598:in `exec_migration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:577:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:752:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:992:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `block in transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:219:in `within_new_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `ddl_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:953:in `block in migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Which email should I remove from the add_devise_to_user.rb file?

```
class AddDeviseToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      # Uncomment below if timestamps were not included in your original model.
      # t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end

  def self.down
    # By default, we don't want to make any assumption about how to roll back a migration when your
    # model already existed. Please edit below which fields you would like to remove in this migration.
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

Comment: it says you have a "duplicate column name: email"...

Comment: Any idea on how I can fix it since I didn't generate these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the `AddDeviseToUsers` migration error stack trace, you may notice that you have a duplicate email column. You already have an email column on the users table and that particular migration is trying to add another one.

I'd advise you to edit AddDeviseToUsers to remove the email column creation. If you're not familiar with Rails directory structure, you may find that file at `db/migrate/xxxxxxxxxxx_add_devise_to_users.rb`

I hope it helps.

Comment: I've add the file. Could you please point me to removing the email column creation

Comment: ok...I'm not sure at ALL what's going on but it finally started working once I followed the trace after running the command over and over and each time I had to comment out the next line. Can you tell me why this file was created if most of it has to be commented out?

Comment: The file is created because Devise(the authentication gem you're using) needs those columns to work properly. Take a look at your db/migrate folder and try to find another migration file with those same definitions, but under a different name. The fact that you had to comment out all of the lines implies that all of the columns were already defined on your db. They could have gotten there from another migration or manually. Did you start your project from scratch or is it based on a template? If it comes from a template, maybe they had a migration for those fields already.